# same code but does not work on jupyter, but works on VS

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried same codes on jupyter notebook and visual studio. The codes work on VS but do not on jupyter notebook. I have experienced the same problem few times and tried to search for the reason, but I did not get the satisfying answer. Could anyone help me understand why this happens? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Works for me on the Jupiter notebook with Python 3. Which python version are you using? Anyway, try to put the code as text whenever possible so that people can copy it easily and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which you have shared is working fine on both jupyter as well as VS code for me. The problem might be arising due to some other piece of code part of your file.

Make sure the instance you are using are not used before or that you haven't assigned any value to the instance 'list' before this. Since, 'list' is a builtin class and reassigning the values to it might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. following your advice, I have checked all the "list" above in the jupyter and found another list was being used. again, appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped!!

Comment: will look forward to helping others like you did :) have a good one!